# vue style tags generated for each component in the index?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

When i use the style tag on a component, and then view the generated code in the browser, i end up with a style tag for every component used.

Is there a way around this?

What is considered best practice with vue and css?

Comment: and a loader to your configuration, include the file at the top of your base `app.js` file, write your code in the external file

Comment: I like using the style tags in the components. I just dont think a whole bunch of style tags in the header on build is a good idea. Surely there must be a way around it?

Comment: I believe its only in development mode. When you make production build it compiles into one or two css files. Its best way in development because you have hot loader